# Install and setup FTP for nginx on Amazon EC2?

Tags: linux, ftp, amazon-ec2

To install `nginx` and `node` on my Amazon EC2 I followed this guide: 
[Installing Node.js on Amazon EC2](https://github.com/d5/docs/wiki/Installing-Node.js-on-Amazon-EC2)

Now I want to get an FTP up and running and set it up so that when I connect to the FTP I automatically land in the correct folder (that will be shown to the world by `nginx`).

How can I do this?